# Showing two k-means cost functions are equal

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

So I am learning about the k-means algorithm for clustering and have seen a couple of different cost functions that can be used, in particular, $$J_{avg} = \sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{x\in C_i}d(x,m_j)^2$$$$J_{IC}=\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{1}{|C_j|}\sum_{x\in C_i}\sum_{x'\in C_i}d(x,x')^2.$$ Now I am trying to show that if $m_j=\frac{1}{C_j}\sum_{x\in C_j}x$ then $J_{IC}=2J_{avg}.$ This makes intuitive sense to me since it seems to be the difference between average distance to the centriod and average distance between two points (which should be double of that to the center). Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: As you probably noticed: no latex rendering here. And your question seems to be independent from the kmeans setting. Kmeans need a metric and the question is: are some metrics the same?

Comment: @sascha k-means does *not* allos arbitrary metrics. Use it with variance only.

Answer (score 0):

For the cost functions to be equivalent they don't have to be exactly equal, just monotonically related so that optimizing one means optimizing the other.

SUM_ij (Xi - Xj)^2 = SUM_ij (Xi - x + x - Xj)^2 = SUM_ij (Xi - x)^2 + (Xj - x)^2 + 2(Xi - x).(x - Xj)

If x is the mean of the Xi then SUM_j (x - Xj) = 0 so the dot product term goes away and you get the sort of connection between the sum of squared distances from the mean and the sum of the squared distances between any two points that I think you need.